# How to add Chosen Groups or Chosen user permissions in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm fairly new to the Django Framework so this might be very easy
I'm trying to replicate the result picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBltZ.png)

using this code i was able to add the Available Groups to the panel

```
   ('Permissions', {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff','is_superuser','groups','user_permissions',)
        }),
```

however i wasn't able to find the name of the attribute for either chosen groups or chosen user permissions.
I would appreciate it if you could point out the name and a link to the django documentation regarding this
below is the picture of the panel i have made so far
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK0Wf.png)

I read the documentation regarding the django admin panel but wasn't able to find the correct name of the attributes.